# how to create database in the specific folder with google gear?

Tags: sqlite, google-gears

When we are using any gear enable site, and we go offline the gear automatically creating folder with /dbName#database ...

assume 2 diff. website is there www.abc.com and www.xyz.com.

when I go online in www.abc.com it should create folder like /abcxyz/dbName#database, And same for www.xyz.com it should also create folder like /abcxyz/dbName#database. So what I mean is both the website should use same SQLite Database.

If this is possible please send me some example code how to achieve this with gear code.

Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

The last time I checked, you couldn't do that: I am pretty sure it is related to security concerns & same origin policy.

Since a site isn't supposed to have access to resources of other sites, I really doesn't make sense to expose additional degrees of liberty at this API level. Furthermore, what value would that confer to the WEB application?  I could only really serve the needs on the client host side which is not really a priority for Gears.

Comment: so is there any way i can create database file in specific folder and use same database for 2 diff. website.